# A grey water bird with brown head

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

- A greyish bird, with brown head and relatively long, pointy beak.
- Size comparable to mallard.
- Spotted in central Poland, on small, artificial pond, populated by mallards and Eurasian coots.
- Photo has been taken today (late September).

[image]

I'd be grateful for any information that could be used to identify this bird.

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is a goosander

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the location and picture I believe this a **Goosander** (*Mergus merganser*) which is the European name, the North American name is the **Common Merganser**.

You can find more information about them [here](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/22680492/0).

[image]

They undergo two main molts, breeding plumage in December and eclipse plumage in May. Here is a description of the eclipse molt by Bent, 1923:

> In May the adult male goosander begins to assume its eclipse plumage.
>   The adult male in August has the crown reddish brown, with a gray
>   tinge; chin white, and the rest of the head and upper neck rich red
>   brown.

By the looks of your photo, you either have 2 females during the breeding plumage phase (January - May) or either sex during the eclipse phase (June - December). It will depend on when the photo was taken.

Here is an image with a breeding plumage male (left) alongside some females:

[image]

References:

```
Bent, Arthur Cleveland. 1923. Smithsonian Institution United States National Museum Bulletin 126 (Part 1): 1-13. United States Government Printing Office
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It looks like a good match, and I've already heard about goosanders in the area - just haven't seen one. This year somone introduced fish, to keep the pond clean -  I guess it become a nice dinner plate.